# How can I account for inconsistent dateFormats in Carbon/Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

I've inherited a Laravel 5 app that uses a database that formerly belonged to a Rails application. As a result, in the date columns (`created_at`, `updated_at`, etc) the date formats are inconsistent, and I'm trying to determine how I can account for this considering Laravel's Carbon integration.

The Rails application stored dates like this: `2017-01-17 23:02:51+00`

The Laravel app includes microseconds, so the dates look like this: `2017-01-17 23:02:51.451741+00`

The problem is that Laravel runs all of it's date functions through Carbon, which parses them according to a global `$dateFormat`, causing the Rails-generated dates to throw the following error:

`Unexpected data found. Data missing`

My first thought was to try and detect whether microseconds were present at the model level, and if not, add `.000000` to the date strings so Carbon plays nice and the data stays intact.

Unfortunately it looks like getting the date with `$this->created_at` passes through Carbon first, so that seems like a dead end. Another issue is that I'm unsure if there are any other date formats that may be lurking around.

I'd like to avoid editing any of the data directly (at least until I'm more familiar with the codebase), but I'm stumped as to the best way to account for multiple formats with Carbon.

Any advice would be very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the raw value of `created_at` you can use `$this->attributes['created_at']` in the model.

That will enable you to apply an accessor to `$this->created_at`, if you wish to.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you create a script that would go through the database, take the created_at values, and standardized them. That way they are all the same and you wouldn't have to worry about adding/removing text in your code.

Comment: This is specifically something I'm trying to avoid for the time being, as it's a large application and I'd like to be able to test for edge cases first before modifying data directly.